# Shopify laravel Missing Authorization key in headers array in production server

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, shopify, shopify-api

I deployed a shopify apps using **laravel and polaris** react in my host.
But my api are getting **500 server error and in laravel.log** Its showing :

```
production.ERROR: Missing Authorization key in headers array {"exception":"[object] (Shopify\\Exception\\MissingArgumentException(code: 0): Missing Authorization key in headers array at /public_html/vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Auth/OAuth.php:226)
[stacktrace]
#0 
/public_html/vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Utils.php(160): Shopify\\Auth\\OAuth::getCurrentSessionId(Array, Array, false)
#1 
/public_html/app/Http/Middleware/EnsureShopifySession.php(54): Shopify\\Utils::loadCurrentSession(Array, Array, false)
```

In **locally its pretty okay**. All api are being called without server error.
I deployed Only web folder to production after build using npm run build with api key
I used this **.env** at production

```
APP_NAME="Shopify PHP App"
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:aLjEjgav7KX1UFyB7JUzySf/d0rV7rvHMsWOdJBnbHE=
APP_DEBUG=false
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_FOREIGN_KEYS=true
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=stack
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=2164114
HOST=https://myhost.com
PORT=8082
SHOPIFY_API_KEY=myapikey
SHOPIFY_API_SECRET=myapikeysecret
SCOPES=write_products
```

**I used two .htaccess,** One in root and another inside public folder.
Inside root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```

inside public folder

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Also i disabled csrf token

```
protected $except = [
    '*'
];
```

where is the problem ?
Anything wrong in my configuration ?

Comment: While calling an api check request headers, does it includes `Authorization` key?

Comment: No. I pass authorization header from frontend . But it doesn't find any authorization header

Comment: Can you share request headers, and source code of api call?